# Can I query data_space names when not in context of the database for multiple databases?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a data set pulled from `sys.master_files`.  The data set looks something like this:

```
database_id filename         physical_name data_space_id
----------- ---------------- ------------- -------------
6           PRIMARY_06       some location 1
6           primary_09       some location 1
21          PRIMARY_01       some location 1
26          PRIMARY_01       some location 1
52          PRIMARY_01       some location 1
75          PRIMARY_01       some location 1
```

I would like to join in the FILEGROUP name to this dataset.  It should just be a matter of joining on `database_id` and  `data_space_id`, but I can't seem to find a function or system view analogous to `sys.master_files` for filegroups/dataspaces.

The brute force method would be to create this list as a temporary lookup using `sp_MSForEachDB`, but I would like to know if there's a better way.

Comment: Well there's definitely a better way than `sp_MSforeachdb`. https://sqlblog.org/2020/08/04/reliable-flexible-replacement-sp_msforeachdb It's also trivial to write your own dynamic SQL that unions the output of the filegroup information from each database. You could also create a view that *looks* like a catalog view and performs this union manually - feasibility depends I guess on how often you add/drop databases.

Comment: Another sp_MsForEachdb replacement, with no cursors this time: http://spaghettidba.com/2011/09/09/a-better-sp_msforeachdb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry. Afraid not. you have to query sys.filegroups and/or sys.data_spaces in each database.